# Adding break to head using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I adding the br in head tag but it get some error on console. How can i add the `br` to the head tag.

```
 var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
 var breaks = document.write('<br>');
 head.appendChild(breaks);
```

I get this error.
TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object.

Any suggestion would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: Why? What's the point of doing this?

Comment: `document.write('<br>');` will overwrite your whole page it should be `document.createElement('br');`

Comment: Why are you trying to put `<br>` in the `<head>`? That part of the document doesn't get rendered, so visual elements are meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't  know why you are trying to add br to head.. but `head.appendChild` needs an object:

```
var br = document.createElement("br");
head.appendChild(br);
```

Comment: Thanks i tried to make trick on viewing source. I tried this one but i didn't get any space on view source.

Comment: @WordPress Page source only shows the original version of the document, you should inspect the DOM (to see the invalidated document.)

Comment: Oh Thanks for your Info @undefined I think I did previously on using php something like <?php echo str_repeat("\n", 100); ?> So I think there is a way to do in jquery but i get a info from you guys thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use `document.createElement`

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var breaks = document.createElement('br');
head.appendChild(breaks);
```

this should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks it doesn't work for me. Nothing saw any space on view source

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery.

```
$("head").append("<br>");
```

Comment: But, as mentioned, why would you wan to add a <br> to the head? The code that's been posted works, but in Chrome it seems to place the extra whitespace in the body, even though the tag is in the head.